# CloudFoundry App subdomain

Tags: cloud-foundry

I admire cloudfoundry.com, especially when deploy the application to the cloudfoundry.com system , that was able to create the subdomain for app it self , make it live on internet , so we can access it directly if we connect to internet.

I've successfully install vcap on public server paas.azure4j.us .

But when I deployed an application and an output said that it was succesfully deployed and make a subdomain like 'myapp.azure4j.us'  .

I understand that we can found sub domain configuration on cloud_controller.yml and deployment.json .

## CMIIW

But when I access it directly from web browser ,why it doesnt work ?

So I have to set it on my /etc/hosts or add subdomain on
DNS manager  of provider to access it.

My Question is , how cloudfoundry.com make them client app's subdomain directly connected to internet when them newly deploy it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the DNS for azure4j.us is set up correctly for this? There seems to be a wild-card domain record set up, if I open myapp.azure4j.us, it doesn't appear to go to a VCAP instance.

Comment: Okay thank you , I've fix it , I give wildcard domain on my DNS MANAGEMENT